# Standard ISO 8601 format of ±HH:MM for ZoneOffset in swagger instead of JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, timezone-offset

I'm currently working on Java application, which works with the orders. In some `@RestController` methods I return an instance of an `Order` class, which contains a `timezone` field.

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Order {
   private ZoneOffset timezone;
}
```

When I generate swagger with spring-boot tools it creates a json for responses, which looks like this

```json
{
"timezone": {
    "totalSeconds": 0,
    "id": "string",
    "rules": {
      "fixedOffset": true,
      "transitions": [
        {
          "offsetBefore": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "string"
          },
          "offsetAfter": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "string"
          },
          "duration": {
            "seconds": 0,
            "nano": 0,
            "negative": true,
            "zero": true,
            "units": [
              {
                "dateBased": true,
                "timeBased": true,
                "durationEstimated": true
              }
            ]
          },
          "gap": true,
          "dateTimeBefore": "2023-02-27T18:33:30.403Z",
          "dateTimeAfter": "2023-02-27T18:33:30.403Z",
          "instant": "2023-02-27T18:33:30.403Z",
          "overlap": true
        }
      ],
      "transitionRules": [
        {
          "month": "JANUARY",
          "timeDefinition": "UTC",
          "standardOffset": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "string"
          },
          "offsetBefore": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "string"
          },
          "offsetAfter": {
            "totalSeconds": 0,
            "id": "string"
          },
          "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
          "dayOfMonthIndicator": 0,
          "localTime": {
            "hour": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0,
            "nano": 0
          },
          "midnightEndOfDay": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which is not human-readable.

I want swagger to generate the default value, like `+01:00` (like it returns in responses, when I send requests to my api).

I tried to use annotations like

```java
@ApiModelProperty(example = "+01:00")
```

or

```java
@ApiParam(defaultValue="+01:00")
```

, but nothing worked out for me.

I know that spring-boot tools can generate a human-readable json for `ZonedDateTime` (like this

```json
"time": "2023-02-27T18:33:30.403Z"
```

). So I hope there is way to make the same thing for `ZoneOffset`.

P.S. I can not replace it is used in different calculations and convert it into string and back seems kind of problematic.

Comment: "default value" is a misleading choice of words. I suggest you edit the title and body to use the correct terms: ***standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format*** of ±HH:MM

Comment: I am not sure what sense it makes for an order to have a `ZoneOffset` attribute such as +01:00. But since you think it is meaningful, I too would try to see if I could serialize it exactly as such a string (only), `+01:00`. I’d somehow wonder if there isn’t a way.

Comment: Because the project is old, we store time as it is on our servers. And not to send messages about order (something can change in the order, or the delivery started...) when it is late, we need to understand users timezone and calculate their time, when any change happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [`io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema`](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html#example--)

```
@Schema(example = "+01:00")
private ZoneOffset timezone;
```

generates the same result as I expected.